# Determining if a Transformation of an Infinite series is isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, isometry

[image]

Hi,

For this problem I am stuck on how to determine whether or not the series is isomorphic. I can show that it is linear, however I am not sure how to determine if the Dim(P) = Dim(V) or how to find the kernel of the transformation.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You have not identified what the target space (codomain) is. Until you do, the question can not be answered.

Comment: I am sure that $V$ is the space of all sequences with only finitely many non-zero items. @BNA Forget about the dimensions. They are both infinite. You have to show that $T$ is bijective. As to the injectivity, let $T(f) = 0$ for some polynomial $f$. Let $f$ have degree $d$. Then $f(0) = f'(0) = \ldots = f^{(d)}(0) = 0$. Try some examples for $f$. E.g., $f(x) = ax^2 + bx+c$. What do you think follows from this condition?